# Adding one php button per line in a table

Tags: php, mysql, post, button

I'm trying to build a very basic table to display the results of a query and allow posting the ID from one row (selected with a button on that row) to another php form for further editing the entry.  A pretty basic todo list.

I've been able to make a nice looking table but am a bit stumped about how to get the TaskID value from the array into the value of the form.

Immediately above and below the form is ?> and

Can someone point out the flaw in my logic?  I've tried using an intermediate variable $tmp but this did nothing.  I've googled and searched but am not sure how to implement this.  I'm not great a java and ajax so many of the other solutions I've spotted on the web haven't panned out.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE ISNULL(AssignedTo)") 
or die(mysql_error());  


echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> 
  <th>Name</th> 
  <th>Priority</th> 
  <th>Description</th> 
  <th>Location</th> 
  <th>Location2</th> 
  <th>Update this Entry</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{

$tmp=$row['TaskID'];
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['TaskID'];
echo "<td>"; 
echo $row['TaskName'];
echo "<td>"; 
echo $row['TaskPriority'];
echo "<td>"; 
echo $row['TaskDesc'];
echo "<td>"; 
echo $row['TaskContainer'];
echo "<td>"; 
echo $row['TaskContainerIdentifier'];
echo "<td>"; 
?>

   <form name="form" method="POST" action="form_updatetask.php">
     <input value=$tmp type="hidden" name="search">
     <input type="submit"  value="Update">
   </form>

<?php
}
   echo "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed html and php which is fine but in your html you used a variable.
This obviously must be within `<?php ?>` tags. Also you need to echo that value like this:

```
<input value="<?php echo $tmp;?>" type="hidden" name="search">
```

so your code will look like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Tasks WHERE ISNULL(AssignedTo)") 
or die(mysql_error());  


echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> 
  <th>Name</th> 
  <th>Priority</th> 
  <th>Description</th> 
  <th>Location</th> 
  <th>Location2</th> 
  <th>Update this Entry</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{

$tmp=$row['TaskID'];
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['TaskID'];
echo "<td>"; 
echo $row['TaskName'];
echo "<td>"; 
echo $row['TaskPriority'];
echo "<td>"; 
echo $row['TaskDesc'];
echo "<td>"; 
echo $row['TaskContainer'];
echo "<td>"; 
echo $row['TaskContainerIdentifier'];
echo "<td>"; 
?>

   <form name="form" method="POST" action="form_updatetask.php">
     <input value="<?php echo $tmp;?>" type="hidden" name="search">
     <input type="submit"  value="Update">
   </form>

<?php
}
   echo "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Holy smokes...I knew it was something simple but I think you broke some sort of speed record answering that!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is one of those language that allows you to break in and out of the parser and include sections, sometimes long ones, of unprocessed raw text. Anything outside of PHP's `<?php … ?>` blocks is treated as plain text and output as-is.

You have in your form this line:

```
<input value=$tmp type="hidden" name="search">
```

This will appear as exactly that in your rendered HTML because the entire line exists outside of the remit of PHP's code parser. To make the variable output in your code, you need to enclose it in `<?php … ?>` tags and echo the value like this:

```
<input value=<?php echo $tmp ?> type="hidden" name="search">
```

If you are on a server with 5.4+ or short_open_tags enabled, you can use this shorter syntax:

```
<input value=<?=$tmp?> type="hidden" name="search">
```

Additionally, it's good practice to always enclose HTML attribute values in quotation marks, so I would recommend you use this line for completeness:

```
<input value="<?php echo $tmp ?>" type="hidden" name="search">
```

As a last note, the `mysql_*` functions are (semi-)deprecated and as a result are no longer recommended for use. PHP has comes with a much faster library called the MySQL Improved Extension (or MySQLi) which is broadly similar to the library you're using, but with `mysqli_connect`, `mysqli_select_db`, `mysqli_query`, etc, and a much greater range of functionality available. I suggest you switch to using these functions as soon as is feasible in your project as the performance and security benefits alone make it worthwhile.

> References:
>
> - https://www.php.net/mysqli

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that.  The nesting has always confused me a bit and sometimes I lose track and miss a set of quotes.